# How to show that $\Bbb C/(-\infty ,0]$ is simply connected space

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I need to show that for $\Bbb C/(-\infty ,0]$ that if I have arbitrary different pathes $\gamma , \eta :[0,1] \to\Bbb C/(-\infty ,0]$ such that $\gamma(0)=\eta(0)=\alpha $ and $\gamma(1)=\eta(1)=\beta $ I have continuous homotopy $H:[0,1]^2 \to \Bbb C/(-\infty ,0]$ such that: $H(0,t) = \gamma (t),H(1,t) = \eta (t),H(s,0) = \alpha,H(s,1) = \beta$
unfortunatily my space isn`t a convex,so how do I define a proper Homotopy and proving it's continuous?

Comment: You could show it's homeomorphic to $\Bbb C$.

Comment: we cannot show it by homeomorphism, sorry...

Comment: It's not convex, but still star-shaped.

Comment: Note that $\Bbb C/(-\infty ,0]$ is star-shaped with center $1$ for example.  You could use the straight line homotopy on each of the paths to obtain homotopies to the center, then concatenate one with the reverse of the other and use the Pasting lemma to show continuity.

Comment: Iv'e tried to build homotopy such that:
$H(s,t)=\gamma(t)*(1-2s)+2s , 0\le s \le 0.5$ and $(2-2s)+\eta(t)(2s-1) ,0.5 \le s \le 1$ does it`s ok?

Comment: $z \mapsto z^2$ is a conformal mapping between the right half-plane and your domain $\Bbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the complex plane using polar coordinate system.
Every points in $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\inf,0]$ can be written as $(\rho,\theta)$, $\rho\in(0,+\inf)$, $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$.
The function $f\colon\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\inf,0]\to\{z\in\mathbb{C}, Re(z)>0\}$ defined as $f(\rho,\theta)=(\rho,\frac{\theta}{2})$ is an homeomorphism, and Imf is a convess space, so the domain is simply connected.

Comment: I noticed that you're looking for an explicit homotopy. The homeomorphism helps you in this search: write the two curves in polar coordinates as $\gamma(t)=(\gamma_{\rho}(t),\gamma_{\theta}(t))$ and $\eta(t)=(\eta_{\rho}(t),\eta_{\theta}(t))$, then the homotopy is $H(s,t)=(1-s)(\gamma_{\rho}(t),\gamma_{\theta}(t))+s(\eta_{\rho}(t),\eta_{\theta}(t))$.

Comment: Iv'e tried to build homotopy such that: $H(s,t)=γ(t)∗(1−2s)+2s,0≤s≤0.5$ and $(2−2s)+η(t)(2s−1),0.5≤s≤1$ does it`s ok?

Comment: No, it's not. In fact your homotopy isn't rel{0,1}: $H(s,0)=\gamma(0)*(1-2s)+2s\ne\gamma(0)$ for $s\ne 0$.

Comment: so how do I find a literal homotopy between 2 pathes with the same start and end?

Comment: I showed it in the previous comment, you have to use polar coordinates

Comment: Maybe you mean $\to\{z\in\mathbb{C}, Re(z)>0\}$

Comment: You are right, I corrected, thanks

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is probably to use that your domain is starshaped with respect to 1. This makes it possible to shrink any closed curve in the domain to the point 1.