# Show that $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}^{\le 0}$ is simply connected

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, homotopy-theory

I thought the most effective way to show that the statement is true is showing that $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}^{\le 0}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ are homeomorphic.

I think the function $f: \mathbb{R}^{2}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}^{\le 0}$ s.t $f(x,y)=(\exp(x)+iy)^2$ is a homeomorphism between these two sets. However, it is very hard for me to show that this function is bijective because there is so much casework which seems unnecessary to me.

Therefore, I would like to know if there is a more effective way to show that $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}^{\le 0}$ is simply connected.

Any enlightenment would be really appreciated.

Updated:

Thanks to Per Manne, I could understand why this should be simply connected. However, it is still hard for me to write it in a formal way. I hope I could get some improvement on my proof wrting below.

My Trial:

Note that $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}^{\le 0}$ is star-like with respect to $1$.  $\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \ast $

Let $\gamma _{1},\gamma _{2}:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}^{\le 0}$ two arbitrary paths satisfying $\gamma _{1}(0)=\gamma _{2}(0)$ and $\gamma _{1}(1)=\gamma _{2}(1)$.

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \{1\}$.

Then, we can see that $\gamma _{1}$ and $f$ are homotopic, and simillarly, $\gamma _{2}$ and $f$ are homotopic by $\ast $.

This implies that, $\gamma _{1}$ and $\gamma _{2}$ are homotopic.

Hence, $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}^{\le 0}$ is simply connected.
$\blacksquare $

Even though the approach seems right, but I feel like I'm missing important parts that makes this formal proof. What should I add more in? (How can I show that $\gamma _{1}$ and $f$ are homotopic, and  $\gamma _{2}$ and $f$ are homotopic by $\ast $ in a formal way?.

Moreover, how can I connect this to the fact $\gamma _{1}$ and $\gamma _{2}$ are homotopic?)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3053186/42969.